# Как записать грамотно условие при выводе бд на страницу html

Tags: php

В бд есть таблица с полями и текстовой информацией. В таблице есть поле message1 которое содержит текст 'опоздание более 15мин' и 'опоздание менее 15мин'. Я не могу понять как построить условие при котором, ,будет так если в cтолбце message1 есть фраза 'опоздание более 15мин' то записывать 0. Если встречается 'опоздание менее 15мин' то записывать 1.
 $row содержит массив с данными из бд

```
foreach($row as $k=>$val) { 
  foreach ($val as $value=>$last) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r ($row);
    echo '</pre>';  
  }
}
```

Comment: обычно делают наоборот: в БД вытаскивается флаг 0 или 1, а уже на уровне представления определяется каким образом это показывать.
В любом случае приведите пример, что у вас содержится в `row` и что вы хотите получить на выходе.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться функцией [strpos](http://www.php.net/strpos) и найти вхождение подстроки 'более' во входных данных. Что-нибудь вроде:

```
$findme   = 'более';
$pos = strpos($row, $findme);

if ($pos === false) {
    print_r('0');
} else {
    print_r('1');
}
```

*И тем не менее, @teran в комментариях прав - в БД имеет смысл хранить только флаги, а развёрнутые фразы подставлять только при выводе данных*